# "Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch" in VBA for JSON extraction with JIRA API

Tags: vba, excel, api, jira

New to the community here. I've done a decent amount of programming but I'm completely new to VBA. Never used it before until now and I was tasked with extracting JSON data from a Jira API into an Excel spreadsheet. I keep getting the error "Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch" and I'm not sure why. I know the error has to do with passing in incorrect types but I've tried changing the Json variable to a String with no success. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

By the way, this is just a trial Jira instance for testing the API functionality.

```
Sub test()

'Authenticate the user
Dim response As String

With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  .Open "POST", "https://apitestsite.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session", False, "admin", "password"
  .setRequestHeader "X-Atlassian-Token:", "nocheck"
  .Send
  response = .responseText
End With

'Query through JSON
Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "GET", "https://apitestsite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/CC-1", False, "admin", "password"
MyRequest.Send

Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(MyRequest.responseText)

MsgBox Json("fields")("summary")

End Sub
```

UPDATE: This is where I am at right now. Updated the code for the authentication and now no errors display from the compiler. Here is the JSONConverter class I am using: github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas. The issue now is that the returned JSON string says, "{"errorMessages":["Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it."],"errors":{}}". So I am able to connect to Jira just fine and return the JSON as a string, it's just that Jira is rejecting my credentials :/

```
Private JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Private JiraAuth As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Sub test()

'Authenticate the user

With JiraAuth
    .Open "POST", "https://apitestsite.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "X-Atlassian-Token:", "nocheck"
    .send " {""username"" : ""admin"", ""password"" : ""password""}"""
    sErg = .responseText
    sCookie = "JSESSIONID=" & Mid(sErg, 42, 32) & "; Path=/Jira" '*** Extract the Session-ID
End With

With JiraService
    Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    MyRequest.Open "GET", "https://apitestsite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/CC-1", False
    MyRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    MyRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    MyRequest.setRequestHeader "Set-Cookie", sCookie '*** see Create a "Cookie"
    MyRequest.send

    Dim Json As String

    Json = MyRequest.responseText

    MsgBox Json
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: which line raises the error?

Comment: Also, you may want to include code for the `JsonConverter` class, since that's not a normal refernce that most users would have available to them.

Comment: Have you checked the response if it is the expected result? Maybe you get back an HTML response due to an error status?

Comment: Possible source of the JsonConverter class: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas

Comment: Thanks for the replies! The compiler says the error occurs at the last line "MsgBox Json("fields")("summary")". Could I just be filtering through the JSON incorrectly? I'll update my question with the JsonConverter class.

Comment: @DavidZemens that link is the exact class I'm using!

Comment: Have you debugged to ensure your `Json` object contains a "fields" (and that "fields" contains "summary")?

Comment: Yeah I have it displayed on my browser. Fields is a root variable and summary is inside of it. I just tried another root variable, "id". Interestingly, it didn't throw an error but displayed a blank message box. The message box should be displaying "10049".

Comment: So if I set Json as a String then type Json = MyRequest.responseText; MsgBox Json; then my the output box says ""errorMessages": [
        "Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it."
    ],
    "errors": {}". So maybe there's an issue authenticating me with my code above?

Comment: Does the specified Issue exist? If so, then it's probably authentication problem would be my guess.

Comment: Yep, definitely exists. Been altering my code for authentication based on other users' success online but it's still not working. No matter what I change I keep getting ""errorMessages": [ "Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it." ], "errors": {}".

Comment: I'm super confused because it's obviously accessing the JSON and trying to authenticate me with the credentials I'm inputting. Why I don't have access is a mystery to me. I tried using the same API URL on POSTMAN with the same login credentials and it worked 100% fine. If I remove the login cedentials in POSTMAN I receive the same error I get right now. Super puzzled here :/

Comment: Is it possible to provide an [mcve] so that others can replicate this issue without extraordinary efforts? For example, I've just created an account with Atlassian but I don't know what else I would have to do in order to reproduce your situation here... This seems like an implementation issue and unless others can replicate what you're doing, it's going to be difficult to troubleshoot to assist you.

Comment: I get this: `your (my) email address doesn't have access to apitestsite.atlassian.net`. Do you?  What is "POSTMAN" and why would you expect credentials for *that* to be applicable to *this*?

Comment: Ignore the POSTMAN comment from above, just wanted to show that the credentials I am using for my code have access to the API. In terms of recreating my scenario, there isn't much else from the code I provided through VBA. If you would like to access the Jira instance or the JSON that should be displaying, you can login to apitestsite.atlassian.net with "jiratestemail82@gmail.com" with the password "password". From there you can type in "https://apitestsite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/CC-1" in another browser tab to view the JSON for that specific API call.

Comment: Added my updated code above and I kept it as short as possible while retaining the same result I am having. Thanks for taking the time to look at all of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to return a valid JSON from the API, which is parseable from the `Jsonconverter` module.

[image]

You were using `MyRequest` object as possibly the wrong type of object. Elsewhere, you're relying on the `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` class.

```
Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
```

So I removed the `MyRequest` and just worked with the `JiraService` object instead. You had a `With JiraService` block but you weren't actually using that object at all, you were executing against the `WinHttpRequest` object within that block.

I also declared all variables, and modified the auth string to use `Const` strings defined at top of module for user/password.

```
Option Explicit
Private JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Private JiraAuth As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Const user As String = "jiratestemail82@gmail.com"
Const pw As String = "password"
Sub test()
Dim sErg$, sCookie$, Json$

'Authenticate the user

With JiraAuth
    .Open "POST", "https://apitestsite.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "X-Atlassian-Token:", "nocheck"
    .send " {""username"" : """ & user & """, ""password"" : """ & pw & """}"""
    sErg = .responseText
    sCookie = "JSESSIONID=" & Mid(sErg, 42, 32) & "; Path=/Jira" '*** Extract the Session-ID
End With

With JiraService
    .Open "GET", "https://apitestsite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/CC-1", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Set-Cookie", sCookie '*** see Create a "Cookie"
    .send
    Json = .responseText
End With

Dim j As Object
Set j = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Json)
MsgBox j("fields")("summary")

End Sub
```

Comment: You are amazing! I was close to getting it to work but I was going about solving it the wrong way. Thanks for describing why it works, too. Greatly appreciated, thanks so much!